# Confusion about remote and branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am pretty new to github and confused about remote and branch. Can I remote is the server version of branch?

The ["Branch"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUsIE.png) here is actaully remote?

So to create a "branch" like that, I need to

```
checkout -b myBranch
```

Then I can make some changes and commit and push to a new remote?
Is that correct?

Comment: Branches exist independent of remote repositories.

Comment: so the screenshot I showed is a remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

In git you create branch as you did and then you do your changes.
Once your changes are ready to be **committed** you use the `git add` to add the changes to the **staging** area and then you commit them.

[image]